# How can I publish posts on Instagram via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I was browsing through the documentation and I wonder if I can publish posts on instagram without being an instagram partner as they are not accepting any partnership at the moment. However, is there also a way to publish posts on instagram if I publish it on the connected facebook page?

Also, any idea if facebook is going to open up Content publishing API for public access?

I had gone through this document to publish to feeds but its supported only for the native apps and also it just passes it to the instagram app.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed
I'm looking for some that could be used to directly publish a post to the instagram.

Do correct me if any of my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Have you found a way to do that?

Comment: Same, there has to be a way.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/apis/